# How does "eulogon/blessing" Hebrews 6:14 compare with "makarios/blessed" Luke 14:15?

Tags: hebrews

**Hebrews 6:13-14**  [NKJV; my emphasis].

> "For when God made a promise to Abraham, because He could swear by no one  greater, He swore by Himself, saying, '*Surely **blessing** I will bless you, and multiplying I will multiply you*'". [eulogon/blessing].

**Luke 14:15**  [NKJV; my emphasis].

> "Now when one of those who sat at the table with Him heard these things, he said to Him, '**Blessed** is he who shall eat bread in the kingdom of God." [makarios/blessed].

"*eulogon*" and "*makarios*" are different parts of speech, but in these verses why are different words used? Do they allude to:

A. different sorts of blessing.

B. different aspects of the same sort of blessing.

C. another explanation for their particular use?

Comment: this may answer your que on makarios which means happy or fortunate, it doesn't really mean "bless", that's eulogon https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60638/blessed-vs-happy-which-translation-is-more-accurate-in-beatitudes-matthew-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no question that the meanings of εὐλογέω (to bless by saying good words) and  μακαρίζω (to make happy by pronouncing a blessing and its associated cognate noun μακάριος) overlap.  Heb 6:14 contains the verb εὐλογέω and Luke 14:15 contains the noun μακάριος.

The precise meanings of these two almost-synonyms is given in many good lexicons:

- **μακάριος** (happy, blessed) - see https://biblehub.com/greek/3107.htm
- **μακαρίζω** (to make happy, bless) - see https://biblehub.com/greek/3106.htm
- **εὐλογέω** (to pronounce good words) - see https://biblehub.com/greek/2127.htm

The difference in the two verses listed in the question involves a set of hebraisms:

In **Heb 6:14**, the author of Hebrews in quoting from an unrecorded pronouncement in typical Hebrew idiom that evokes a an extreme blessing and double format:

- Surely blessing I will bless you, and multiplying I will multiply you

That is, the great blessing emphasis (because of the repetition) is to result in great multiplying of Abraham's descendants.

By contrast, in **Luke 14:15**, Jesus is not pronouncing a blessing but making a predictive promise - people in the Kingdom of God will be "happy" ie, in a state of μακάριος.  That is, Jesus is stating a simple fact about the future state of those in the spiritual kingdom of God.

Thus, the two are fundamentally different but their meanings clearly overlap.